# Is there a reason not to merge my resume and portfolio?

Tags: resume, portfolio

I work as a designer and currently have my resume in the same (styled) PDF file as my portfolio. It's clearly readable and scannable, so I'm not worried about that part. I don't upload my resume or portfolio on job sites, I apply through company forms or email.

I can't have most of my portfolio uploaded on a site like Behance due to publishing restrictions from previous jobs.

Is there any reason *not* to merge the two files? Or should I have 1 with just the resume and one with resume + portfolio?

Comment: What are you a designer of? In cases where the vacancy does not have an application form as such, do they normally ask for both a CV and portfolio anyway?

Comment: @Kozaky a digital designer, I've personally never applied for a job where they didn't ask for both. I've even seen a couple where they initially only asked for a portfolio and the CV came during the second interaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I've personally never applied for a job where they didn't ask for both. I've even seen a couple where they initially only asked for a portfolio and the CV came during the second interaction. -- [*Summer*'s comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123993/is-there-a-reason-not-to-merge-my-resume-and-portfolio#comment391647_123993)

From a simple Human Resources management perspective, they may need them both to be separated to handle your process.

For example, their system may store all employees/collaborators CVs through a form where the file size is restricted to 2 MB. If you add your portfolio in the same PDF, the recruiter handling your process may request to you later to separate it from the CV.